# Same C pointer showing different values?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I'm running this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
  int num = 1025;
  int *poinTer = &num;
  char *pointChar = poinTer+1;
  *pointChar = 'A';

  printf("Size of Integer: %d\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("Address: %d, Value: %d\n", poinTer, *poinTer);
  printf("Address: %d, Value: %c\n", poinTer+1, *(poinTer+1));
  printf("Address: %d, Value: %c\n", pointChar, *pointChar);
}
```

*pointChar and *(poinTer+1) should output same result but the output that I'm getting is different. *pointChar is not outputting any value:

```
Size of Integer: 4
Address: 1704004844, Value: 1025
Address: 1704004848, Value: A
Address: 1704004673, Value:
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Here is undefined behavior.:) The expression poinTer+1 points to beyond the object num.

Comment: It seems you mean char *pointChar = ( char * )poinTer+1

Comment: Also you may not use the conversion specifier  %d with pointers.

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined.  You're lucky not to get an access violation since you never allocate space for pointTer + 1 (num + 4 bytes).  What you probably did was trash pointChar in the act of of assigning 'A' to its own location on the stack.

Comment: The pointer value 1704004673 is hex 65910C41. The 41 in the end is your 'A' char. What you did when assigning `*pointChar = 'A'`is modifying pointer itsefl ; in other words, `char *pointChar = poinTer+1`make pointChar points to itself because it is right afer poinTer on the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform `+ 1` on a pointer, it does not necessarily increase the memory address by 1. It increases it by `sizeof(*ptr)`.

In this case, `poinTer + 1` is equivalent to `(char*)poinTer + sizeof(int)`. This actually makes dealing with arrays much easier.

The good old fashioned `ptr[i]` is syntactic sugar for `*(ptr + i)`. So, if you have an array of 10 integers, `ptr[4]` will point to the 5th element rather than 4 bytes away from the base address (since integers are generally 4 or 8 bytes).

So what you've actually done is:

1. Create an `int` (`num`) on the stack and gave it the value `1025`
2. Created a `int*`(`poinTer`) on the stack and assigned it the memory address of `num`
3. Incremented the pointer by `sizeof(int)` (which unintentionally points to a different memory address), then cast it to a `char*` and assigned it to a new pointer.
4. Assigned the byte pointed to at this new memory address the value `65` (`'A'`).

This is probably what you wanted to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
  int num = 1025;
  int *poinTer = &num;
  char *pointChar = (char*)poinTer + 1;
  *pointChar = 'A';

  printf("Size of Integer: %d\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("Address: %d, Value: %d\n", poinTer, *poinTer);
  printf("Address: %d, Value: %c\n", (char*)poinTer + 1, *((char*)poinTer+1));
  printf("Address: %d, Value: %c\n", pointChar, *pointChar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this clearly. I'm actually confused with how pointers are actually stored in memory. I thought they're just stored as Integers which doesn't seem to be correct. They seem to be containing type as well.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala got it. I understood good details now. I have one more small doubt. char *pointChar = (char *) poinTer + 4; will lead to an undefined memory area, right? Since, we reserved 4 bytes for integer initially, we'll be able to change things up to +3 but after that compiler will give us any random memory, right?

Comment: @KshitijKumar sort of yes, assuming `sizeof (int)` is 4. The  `+ 4` is special because it points "just past the end" and it is legal to calculate, but you cannot retrieve the value it *points to*. But if the pointer would be out of bounds. i.e. not even just past the end (for example + 5 there), the behaviour of the arithmetic itself is undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying. I think most of the parts are clear now.